# Search and mark in two-dimensional Java-Array

Tags: java, arrays, search

I have an two-dimensional Array in Java. The values are like:

```
2 1 0 2 1 
1 0 2 2 2
1 1 1 2 2
0 0 0 2 2
```

I want to change now all "2"s to a 1, but only the ones who are bordering the other ones. So after saying "Change (4|4) to "2", I want to have my Array like this:

```
2 1 0 1 1 
1 0 1 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1
```

What is the fastest way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by "bordering the other ones?"

Comment: As you can see at my example. the 2 at (0|0) shouldn't get changed. Just the ones who are next to the other 2s.

Comment: So if a 2 shares a "side" with another 2 you change it

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your working with a two dimensional array:

```
have int x and y set to 0
start from [x][y] on the array
Step 1: Check to if number equals "2"
  If it does and:
  0<x<4 and 0<y<4: Check [x-1][y-1],[x][y-1],[x][y+1],[x-1][y],[x+1][y], and [x+1][y+1]
  x=0 and 0<y<3: Check [x][y-1],[x][y+1],[x+1][y], and [x+1][y+1]
  x=4 and 0<y<3: Check [x-1][y-1],[x][y-1],[x][y+1],[x-1][y]
  0<x<4 and y=0: Check [x][y+1],[x-1][y],[x+1][y], and [x+1][y+1]
  0<x<4 and y=3: Check [x-1][y-1],[x][y-1],[x-1][y],[x+1][y]
  and so on....
check to see if [x][y] = any of the checks
   if so: store a 1 in [x][y] in an alternative array of the same size (lets call it flags)
iterate and repeat from step 1 until you have gone through the entire array
run through the flags and if the value is 1 at any address [x][y] change the corresponding value in our original array to "1".
```

sorry its a bit wordy and maybe confusing, please let me know if I need to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Where is your code of what you've tried so far?

You could try using a nested for loop, then put if-else statements in the inner loop that

1. Will look at the values to the left and right of the index

2. If it is next to a 2 (and is a 2), will swap/assign the 2 in the index w/ a 1, otherwise it will just leave it alone.

Are you looking to make this scalable so that it would work with any array of 0s, 1s and 2s or just this exact array that you provided?

Please let me know if you need any clarification and include your code so that we can have something to work off of.

Answer (score 0):

This example uses 2D array as array of arrays.

1. It generates 2D array with random numbers:

   - array[][] is the source array and all replacement routine will be performed in replaced[][] array (which is a copy of source one).
   - SIZE_I - number of rows and SIZE_J - number of columns;
   - RANGE_FROM - minimum number in array and RANGE_TO - maximum number;
   - SEARCH - number to search;
   - REPLACE - number to replace.
   - quantity - number or found and replaced items.
2. It prints source array to screen;
3. It checks source array for matching SEARCH constant with array item array[i][j]. Depending on item's location, several conditions should be met to replace this item in replaced[][] array and to increase quantity variable by one.
4. It prints replaced array to screen and number of replaced items.

I believe you can gain performance by using 2D array as one array.
For example your 2D array may be represented as {2,1,0,2,1,1,0,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,0,0,0,2,2} but you should handle it properly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
final int RANGE_FROM = 0;
final int RANGE_TO = 2;
final int SEARCH = 2;
final int REPLACE_TO = 1;
final int SIZE_I = 4;
final int SIZE_J = 5;
int quantity = 0;
int array[][] = new int[SIZE_I][SIZE_J];
int replaced[][] = new int[SIZE_I][SIZE_J];

// Generate arrays
for (int i = 0; i < SIZE_I; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < SIZE_J; j++) {
    array[i][j] = (int) (RANGE_FROM + Math.random() * (RANGE_TO - RANGE_FROM + 1));
    replaced[i][j] = array[i][j];
    }
}

// Display array
System.out.println("Source array:");
for (int x[]: array) {
    for (int y: x) {
    System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();

// Check array
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    if (i == 0 && j == 0) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i+1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i == 0 && j == array[i].length - 1) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i+1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j-1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i == array.length -1 && j == 0) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i-1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i == array.length -1 && j == array[i].length - 1) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i][j-1] == SEARCH || array[i-1][j] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i == 0 && j != 0 && j != array[i].length - 1) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i][j-1] == SEARCH || array[i+1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i != 0 && i != array.length - 1 && j == array[i].length - 1) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i][j-1] == SEARCH || array[i-1][j] == SEARCH || array[i+1][j] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i == array.length - 1 && j != 0 && j != array[i].length - 1) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i][j-1] == SEARCH || array[i-1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else if (i != 0 && i != array.length - 1 && j == 0) {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i-1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH || array[i+1][j] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (array[i][j] == SEARCH && (array[i-1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j+1] == SEARCH || array[i+1][j] == SEARCH || array[i][j-1] == SEARCH)) {
        quantity++;
        replaced[i][j] = REPLACE_TO;
        }
    }
    }       
}

// Display replaced array
System.out.println("Replaced array:");
for (int x[]: replaced) {
    for (int y: x) {
    System.out.print(y + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Replace quantity: " + quantity);
System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on your answer so that it's clear what your code does?